# How can I create a Svelte component that uses properties from a nested component?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, properties, svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to create an IconButton component that uses a nested Icon component. I can't figure out how to use the `title` property from the Icon within the IconButton. Ultimately I want to do something like `<IconButton title="design" />` which will render the correct icon from that title prop.

My Icon.svelte component:

```
<script>
  export let title = "default";
  export let width = "24px";
  export let height = "24px";
  export let focusable = false;
  let icons = [
    {
      box: 24,
      title: "design",
      svg: `<path d="M5 8V20H9V8H5ZM3 7L7 2L11 7V22H3V7ZM19 16V14H16V12H19V10H17V8H19V6H15V20H19V18H17V16H19ZM14 4H20C20.2652 4 20.5196 4.10536 20.7071 4.29289C20.8946 4.48043 21 4.73478 21 5V21C21 21.2652 20.8946 21.5196 20.7071 21.7071C20.5196 21.8946 20.2652 22 20 22H14C13.7348 22 13.4804 21.8946 13.2929 21.7071C13.1054 21.5196 13 21.2652 13 21V5C13 4.73478 13.1054 4.48043 13.2929 4.29289C13.4804 4.10536 13.7348 4 14 4V4Z" fill="white"/>`,
    },
    {
      box: 24,
      title: "user",
      svg: `<path d="M12 14C14.2091 14 16 12.2091 16 10C16 7.79086 14.2091 6 12 6C9.79086 6 8 7.79086 8 10C8 12.2091 9.79086 14 12 14ZM12 8C13.1046 8 14 8.89543 14 10C14 11.1046 13.1046 12 12 12C10.8954 12 10 11.1046 10 10C10 8.89543 10.8954 8 12 8Z" /><path d="M4 22C2.89543 22 2 21.1046 2 20V4C2 2.89543 2.89543 2 4 2H20C21.1046 2 22 2.89543 22 4V20C22 21.1046 21.1046 22 20 22H4ZM4 4V20H7C7 17.2386 9.23858 15 12 15C14.7614 15 17 17.2386 17 20H20V4H4ZM15 20C15 18.3431 13.6569 17 12 17C10.3431 17 9 18.3431 9 20H15Z" />`,
    },
  ];
  let displayIcon = icons.find((e) => e.title === title);
</script>


<svg
  class={$$props.class}
  {focusable}
  {width}
  {height}
  viewBox="0 0 {displayIcon.box} {displayIcon.box}"
>
  {@html displayIcon.svg}
</svg>
```

This component works great, and I can use icons with no issue `<Icon title="design" />`, and it clearly exports a `title` prop. How do I make it so I can use that prop in a parent component?
IconButton.svelte:

```
<script>
  import Icon from './Icon.svelte'
</script>


<button title={title}>
  <Icon />
</button>
```

I am trying to use the IconButton component in another component like so:

```
<IconButton title="design" />
```

The error I'm getting is `Cannot read property 'svg' of undefined` ... Any ideas?

I've also tried:

```
<button title={Icon.title}>
  <Icon />
</button>
------------
<button bind:title={title}>
  <Icon {title} />
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Icon` component is not exporting the title prop, it's exporting control over the title prop. So in your parent component `IconButton` you should also be using `export let title` then passing that through to the `Icon` component.

`IconButton.svelte`

```
<script>
  import Icon from './Icon.svelte'
  export let title
</script>


<button {title}>
  <Icon {title}/>
</button>
```

Then use it in any other file like you showed `<IconButton title="design" />`

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ee13c00b072f46888092d5fe6bfbf677?version=3.37.0) and here's the Svelte tutorial on [Exporting props](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/declaring-props).